pydantic: default values for None fields
Update:
Inspired by @chepner's answer, I change the validator as follows:
    @field_validator("age", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def lower_age(cls, value: int) -> Union[int, None]:
        if value is None or pd.isna(value):
            return cls.model_fields["age"].default
        else:
            return value - 1

According to the official Pydantic guide, a value of None is a valid value for an optional field with a default value.
How can I change it such that None value will be replaced by the default value?
My use case is a record in a Pandas dataframe, such that some of the fields can be None:
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator
from typing import Optional, Union
import pandas as pd
import json

class Person(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: Optional[int] = 10

    @field_validator("age", mode="before")
    @classmethod
    def lower_age(cls, value: int) -> Union[int, None]:
        return None if value is None or pd.isna(value) else value - 1
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    df_person = pd.DataFrame({
        "name": ["Alice", "Bob"],
        "age": [10, None]
    })

    person_list = df_person.to_dict(orient="records")
    for p in person_list:
        m = Person.model_validate(p)
        print(json.dumps(m.model_dump(), indent=4))

In this MWE, I wish that Bob will get a value of 10, not null.
I know that I can change the field_validator such that it will return the default value, but this means I have to enter the default value twice.

typing.Optional doesn't mean optional in the sense you are thinking; it's really just a synonym for "something or None". Also, you should distinguish between the field being optional (it's not: it should really have type int) and the __init__ parameter used to initialize it being optional.

I.e., a proper instance of Person always has an int-valued age attribute. You may or many not be required to provide a int value when instantiating Person to enforce that.

If I define age: int = 10 (without the Optional), my code gets a ValidationError: Input should be a valid integer, which makes sense, because Pydanic considers None as a value, which in this case, does not pass validation.

Here's a question: do you have an external source (the data frame) that takes it upon itself to use None as a sentinel in place of a valid age, or are you supplying None because you defined Person.age to have type Optional[int]?

Ideally, the syntax wouldn't conflate the idea of the type of an attribute and the type of value __init__ will accept to produce a value for the attribute.

I get the data from an external source. I can of course deal with this in various ways. From a design perspective, I'd like to have one place, the Pydantic model, that deals with all the validation.

If you weren't using Pydantic, I would recommend the following structure. The default value is a property of __init__, not the attribute itself.
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int

    def __init__(self, name: str, age: int = 10):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 10

If you wanted to set the default age "explicitly" using a sentinel like None, I would change __init__ to
def __init__(self, name: str, age: Optional[int] = None):
    self.name = name
    if age is not None:
        self.age = age
    else:
        self.age = 10

The problem introduced by Pydantic is that it conflates the type of the attribute with the type of the parameter that __init__ uses to initialize the attribute. I will say up front that I am not familiar enough with Pydantic to know what a good workaround is, but with the standard library dataclasses, I advocate defining a separate init var to initialize the field. For example,
@dataclass
class Person:
    name: str
    age: int = field(default=10, init=false)

    age_: InitVar[Optional[int]] = None

    def __post_init__(self, age_):
        if age_ is not None:
            self.age = age_
        else:
            self.age = fields(Person)[1].default

It's more code, but it

Accurately types the age attribute
Distinguishes between providing no value to initialize age and providing a sentinel to trigger the default value assignment.

(Similar, if not nearly identical, code for Pydantic should be possible.)

Inspired by your solution, I took the default value from the class:
    def lower_age(cls, value: int) -> Union[int, None]:
        if value is None or pd.isna(value):
            return cls.model_fields["age"].default
        else:
            return value - 1


